# import variables if file exists

Tags: python, django

I have two Python files on the same level in my Django app.

- settings.py
- SECRET.py

I want to import the variables from SECRET.py in case the file exists.

```
# This code checks if you have the SECRET.py file to connect to the live server
if Path("SECRET.py").is_file():
    print("Live Database")
    from .SECRET import *
else:
    print("Local Database")
    NAME = 'blog_db'
    USER = 'postgres'
    PASSWORD = 'admin'
    HOST = 'localhost'
    PORT = '5432'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': NAME,
        'USER': USER,
        'PASSWORD': PASSWORD,
        'HOST': HOST,
        'PORT': PORT,
    }

}
```

The code keeps connecting to the local database; prints "Local Database", even though I have the SECRET.py file

Comment: Your code tries to read the file from the current working directory. This directory might or might not be the same as the directory where your script is.

Answer (score 1):

You could also wrap it inside a `try..except` block

```
try:
  from .SECRET import *
except ImportError as error:
  # Do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the main directory name to access it

`if Path("myBlog/SECRET.py").is_file():`